# How to limit a sed replacement to everything after a particular symbol?

Tags: bash, sed, replace

I am using `sed` to replace various text within a file, e.g.:

```
sed -i "s/a/b/g" ./file.txt
```

Each line in my file contains, `]`, which is a closing square bracket and a space. I do not want to make replacements to anything before this on the line. Here are some sample lines:

```
This is some text ] This is some other text.
                    ^
```

I have placed a carrot to mark the place where the replacement can begin. Other closing square brackets might appear later on the line, but never before, e.g.:

```
This is some more text ] This is yet some other text ] This is some more.
                         ^
```

This would replace any matches after the carrot. The later square bracket it not important.

- How can I limit `sed` to replace only the matches found after the first `]` appearing on a line?

Comment: Is it after the first `]` or after the first `] `(closing-bracket followed by a space)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answers so far only replace "a" if it occurs once after "]". Since you use the `g` global specification, I assume that "a" may occur more than once after the closing bracket and you want to replace all of them. In order to do this, use the "divide and conquer" method.

```
$ echo "foo abc ] bar ] baz" | sed 's/] /&\n/;h;s/.*\n//;s/a/X/g;x;s/\n.*//;G;s/\n//'
foo abc ] bXr ] bXz
```

This will only consider the first closing square bracket.

Comment: Strictly speaking you are replacing "a" if it occurs once after `"] "`. The first command should read `s/]/]\n/`.

Comment: As is if your example were `echo "foo abc ]bar ] baz"` your result would be `foo abc ]bar ] bXz`.

Comment: @potong: The OP stated that the first closing square bracket is followed by a space.

Comment: I beg your pardon. I should have read the question more closely and not the summary.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
sed -i 's/^\([^]]*].*\)a/\1b/' file.txt
```

Note that the `-i` flag you use is a non-posix extension.

Comment: +1: I have some reservations about the `\+` portion; I think that should be a simple `*` since there's nothing that says the close square bracket cannot be the first character on the line.  The `-i` option is a GNU `sed` extension; that should be noted, too (though it is part of the question).

Comment: This will not replace multiple occurrences on the same line, though. You could add a conditional loop but that would complicate things somewhat.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Duly noted.  See my changes.